# Is it possible to find on which pages Adsense units are active?

Tags: google-adsense

In Google Adsense there is an ad unit that is showing as Active, even though I am sure it's not on any of my pages. I checked the ID against my entire website folder with `grep` and nothing came up.

Under "Performance Reports" the ad unit appears to get an average of 4 impressions each day. Where might these ads be showing up? From a (really) old cache, perhaps? Is there any way to find out exactly what pages gave those ad impressions?

Comment: +1 @DisgruntledGoat: Off the top of my head, are you sure the GREP command is correctly formatted? Not sure if posting it would be an issue, but clearly if there was an issue with the GREP, that's the source of the issue; not something else.

Comment: Is your AdSense account linked to your Analytics account? If so, you might see more information about the source of the ad impressions under Traffic Sources > AdSense > Top AdSense content (in Google Analytics).

Comment: @blunders: Yes I'm sure it is correct. I just searched for the unit ID. (Plus, searching for an active unit ID finds that file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find exactly what you want, but you've got this thing called URL Channels in Adsense, which lets you track clicks by specific URLs.  So if you know roughly where the ads might be getting served, you can set up channels to cover those sections.  It doesn't have to be specific pages, you can start further up and narrow it down. i.e. channel 1 is example.com/blog, channel 2 is example.com/store and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, adsense reports doesn't provide 'ad unit' and 'sites' linking report or I've also failed to find it.

Apart from cache (which ideally should refresh after few weeks), another possibility (which I have witnessed with my sites) is perhaps a scraper or user has posted your entire content in some forum or webpage (along with your adsense code) which keeps the ad unit alive somewhere even when you've changed that on your website.